# MPVolumeView not showing audio routes on iOS 11

Tags: ios11, mpvolumeview

My app displays MPVolumeView button. When no earphone or bluetooth headset is not connected, clicking on this button shows two options. iPhone and iPhone speaker (for speaker and ear piece). This was perfectly fine till iOS 10. But on iOS 11, this button is disabled. It shows available routes only when connected to wireless headset.

I do not see any change or deprecated APIs in MPVolumeView. Anyone else seeing this issue?

Also a thing to note here is I still see old volume control indicator while I read about volume control indicator designed differently on iOS 11.

Answer (score 3):

Figured out that I need to use AVRoutePickerView on iOS 11. This offers audio route options and also volume slider.